# Using category theory, prove that a Banach space is reflexive iff its dual is reflexive

Tags: category-theory, reflexive-space

I'm trying to prove the following result

> A banach space is reflexive if and only if its dual is reflexive

in the most *category theoretical* way I can.

I managed to prove one implication in a *not too* categorical way and am now stuck with the other one.
I'd appreciate any help with dealing with this problem, either for solving the other implication, either for solving both at once or either for solving the first one in an even more categorical way.

---

My proof:

We have a contravariant functor $(-)^*:\textbf{Ban}\to \textbf{Ban}$ that assigns to every Banach space its dual, and to every morphism (Bounded linear operator)  $T:E\to F$ its transpose $T^*:F^*\to E^*$.

If we let $J_X$ be the canonical embedding of $X$ in its dual $X^*$ $(x\mapsto ev_x)$. The hypothesis that for a Banach space $E$, $J_E:E\to E^{**}$ is a Banach space isomorphism means it's an isomorphism in the category $\textbf{Ban}$, thus by applying the functor, we get an isomorphism $J_E^*:E^{***}\to E^*$ such that for every $\psi\in E^{***}$ and $x\in E$ $$J_E^*(\psi)(x)=\psi(J_E(x))$$

and there exists an isomorphism $\Phi:E^*\to E^{***}$ such that  $J_E^*\; \Phi = id_{E^*}$.

Since we also have that for every $f\in E^*$ and $x\in E$
$$J_E^*J_{E^*}(f)(x)=J_{E}^*(ev_f)(x)=ev_f(J_E(x))=ev_f(ev_x)=f(x)$$ then $J_E^*J_{E^*}(f)=f$ which yields $J_E^*J_{E^*}=id_{E^*}$.

We deduce that $\Phi=J_{E^*}$ and thus, $E^*$ is reflexive since $J_E$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: The claim you want to prove is not "categorical": it is a property of Banach spaces.

Comment: The quickest categorical way to see the direction you have is that $(-)^*$ is a functor, thus preserves isomorphisms. So if $E \cong E^{**}$, we hit this with $(-)^*$ to see $E^* \cong E^{***}$. As Mariano has already pointed out, the other direction is not true in categories with similar properties to $\mathsf{Ban}$, so there's little hope of a "categorical" proof.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Wait, we still have to add that the image of $E → E^{**}$ by $(-)^*$ is a retract of the canonical map $X^*→X^{***}$ for this to work. If we add that $(-)^*$ is conservative on embeddings, we also get that $E$ is reflexive if $E^*$ is. The distinction between what is "categorical" and what is not is not very clear to me here, because one can always ask what structure of the category makes the reasoning possible...

Comment: As @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, you can't do this with category theory. I think what you want to do is cast this fact in categorical language.

Comment: @JonathanZ supports MonicaC  that's right.